# Same native compilation for different distributions

Tags: fedora, compiling

Can I use a native build from fedora on ubuntu? What is the difference in compilation between distributions?

Comment: The answer is - it depends. In general, no. But what are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: Linking against say just the C library might work, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The location of libraries might differ between fedora on ubuntu. This could cause a build for fedora not to function on ubuntu and vice versa.